# How to install a Delphi XE5 application permanently on a Mac

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am very new to Mac application development and I seem to be missing a step to permanently install a Delphi XE5-built (FireMonkey) application on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.7.5...

Note that I do not want to publish to the App Store - I just want to install the executable produced by Delphi on my Mac.

I am able to successfully compile the very simple app, and run/debug it on the Mac (connected via a LAN) from my Windows 7 development machine (where Delphi XE5 is installed). What I am missing is being able to deploy (or install) i.e. permanently transfer the executable onto the Mac so that I could run it directly on the Mac, when not connected to the Windows machine.

When I try to run the Delphi-produced executable that I manually copied to the Mac, I get

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcgunwind.1.0.dylib`

I would appreciate some newbie guidance here...

**UPDATE 1:** 
I found [Delphi XE2 Firemonkey sample app not running on a MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271317), and was able to locate `libcgunwind.1.0.dylib` in the Platform Assistant's `MacOS` folder. However, when I copy it to the folder where I placed the Delphi-produced files and try to run my app, it starts, but in addition to the GUI front end it shows the bash console and accepts input only through the console...

Obviously I don't understand how Mac applications work...

**UPDATE 2**:
I found `RADPaServer/scratch-dir` under my user folder and it seems to contain properly formatted application package that I can run directly from the Mac, even if I move it elsewhere on the Mac's HD. However, I wonder if that's where I *should* be looking for it...

The executable package appears to be re-created there every time I run the app from Delphi on Windows, as well as when I just click `"Project|Deploy"` in Delphi IDE, without running it.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Have I found the right place to scoop the app from?

Comment: The scratch dir is the proper location, according to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/PAServer,_the_Platform_Assistant_Server_Application#The_Scratch_Directory).

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159485/how-to-deploy-a-firemonkey-application-for-mac-osx

Answer (score 2):

To install the app you must just copy it's folder to /Applications, e.g.

```
cd ~/RADServer/scratch-dir/<your-name> OS X profile
cp -a <app-name>.app /Applications
```

If you want to make .dmg file it's another matter. I prefer text-based tools, so I use

```
hdiutil create -fs HFS+ -volname <volume name> -srcfolder RADPAServer/scratch-dir/<your-name> OS\ X\ profile/ ~/<dmg-file-name>.dmg
```

Comment: this info may also be useful: https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-sign-macos-pkg-files-for-deployment-with-hexnode-mdm/